# Declaring generic Dictionary with bounded type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I need to declare a `Dictionary` having a `Type` as key and an instance as value.

I need to limit key Type to a certain class hierarchy.

For a Java Map, I can do something like:

```
Map<Class<? extends MySuperClass>, ? extends MySuperClass>
```

How can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: Just to make sure, you will have 0 or 1 instances of any specific Type key (which is then stored as the value)?  That seems a bit weird.

Comment: @ryanyuyu yes, exactly

Comment: Well the "obvious" solution is to just have the value typed as a general `MySuperClass` and then just put type-checking and casting everywhere.  But I suppose you're looking for something better than that.  I'm not sure that Dictionaries can return a value `Type` that changes.

Comment: Sounds like some kind of constraints of dictionary key. Why not  simply to check it before adding to dictionary?

Comment: @Sinatr I'm quite new to .NET C# so I'm looking for a clean approach to this problem. I don't necessarily need a "Java approach"

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but couldn't you just do `var dict = Dictionary<KeyClass<ValueClass>, ValueClass>`? You don't really need to do any extra work; anything that derives from `KeyClass<ValueClass>` can be used as a key, anything that derives from `ValueClass` can be used as a value.

Comment: @Asad `Class<>` is a concrete class in Java, not a mock name. It has an equivalent meaning of `Type` in C#, but it also allows to specify constraints on assigned values.

Comment: @davioooh Ah, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Do not expose `Dictionary` directly, this way you can control manually when to add

```
public void AddToDictionary(Type key, object value)
{
    if(!key.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(SomeBaseClass))
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be an inherited from SomeBaseClass type");
    dictionary.Add(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Sinatr's approach of exposing a method for adding to the dictionary instead of the dictionary itself is a very good idea. The only downside is that you get no compile time safety; if some code added an object of the wrong type you wouldn't find out till runtime.

Using generics, however, we can tweak the method so that adding objects is foolproof:

```
public void AddToDictionary<T>(T value) where T: MySuperClass
{
    dict.Add(typeof(T), value);
}
```

Now it is impossible to write a program that adds objects of the wrong type and still compiles.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `typeof` to get the type of the class so something like:

```
Map<System.Type, object>
```

I am not sure how you would enforce the extends for this. That should probably happen as a test before adding to the map.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
public class MyType<TBase>
{
    private Type Value;

    protected MyType()
    {
    }

    public static implicit operator Type(MyType<TBase> type)
    {
        return type.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyType<TBase>(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (!typeof(TBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        return new MyType<TBase> { Value = type };
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var type = obj as MyType<TBase>;

        return type != null && Value.Equals(type.Value);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Dictionary<MyType<MySuperClass>, MySuperClass> dict = new Dictionary<MyType<MySuperClass>, MySuperClass>();
dict.Add(typeof(MyClass1), new MyClass1());
```

The `MyType` has implicit operators from/to `Type`, so it is quite simple to use. You simply cast a `Type` to a `MyType` (or a `MyType` to a `Type`) and it just works. Example of `TryGetValue()`:

```
MySuperClass ms;

if (!dict.TryGetValue(typeof(MyClass1), out ms))
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

**Note that the checks are done at runtime!**